# Volusion: How to show all products in home page?

Tags: volusion

I have a Volusion store I assign categories to all products so the products are just shows in their concern categories. I want to show all products in my home page when first time my store load.

I tried to assign admin but no option is there.

Answer (score 0):

In the Admin, go to Design / Product Display Settings / Home Page Featured (link on left). Increase the Display Rows and Display Columns values to accommodate your inventory.   More info here https://support.volusion.com/hc/en-us/articles/210106697-Product-Display-Settings#featured_products